# Laravel scheduler no timezone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to make cron jobs with Laravel 8

```
$schedule->command('myCommand')->daily()->timezone('Europe/Paris');
```

I have an error when I run on server

```
php artisan schedule:list
```

php artisan schedule:list

```
 TypeError 

  DateTime::setTimezone(): Argument #1 ($timezone) must be of type DateTimeZone, null given

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleListCommand.php:42
     38▕                 $event->expression,
     39▕                 $event->description,
     40▕                 (new CronExpression($event->expression))
     41▕                             ->getNextRunDate(Carbon::now()->setTimezone($event->timezone))
  ➜  42▕                             ->setTimezone($this->option('timezone', config('app.timezone')))
     43▕                             ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P'),
     44▕             ];
     45▕         }
     46▕ 

      +14 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

And

```
php artisan schedule:run
No scheduled commands are ready to run.
```

Tried:

```
  TypeError 
    
      DateTime::setTimezone(): Argument #1 ($timezone) must be of typ
...

e(Carbon::now()->setTimezone($event->timezone))
      ➜  42▕                             ->setTimezone($this->option('timezone', config('Europe/Paris')))
         43▕                             ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P'),
         44▕             ];
         45▕
          Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Comment: once try static value instead of `config('app.timezone'))`, may be config clear issue then.

Comment: same error, I edit my original post

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,
an

> Composer update

solve the problem in my side !